# C# - Remove duplicate lines within a text file

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Could someone demonstrate how a file is checked for duplicate lines, and then any duplicates are removed either overwriting the existing file, or create a new file with the duplicate lines removed

Comment: @Felice Pollano No mate, unless I am a 28 year old student :D

Comment: ok, but anyway you are asking for a job done...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using .NET4 then you could use a combination of [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) and [`File.WriteAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383463.aspx):

```
var previousLines = new HashSet<string>();

File.WriteAllLines(destinationPath, File.ReadLines(sourcePath)
                                        .Where(line => previousLines.Add(line)));
```

This functions in pretty much the same way as LINQ's `Distinct` method, with one important difference: the output of `Distinct` isn't guaranteed to be in the same order as the input sequence. Using a `HashSet<T>` explicitly does provide this guarantee.

Comment: HashSet<T> does not preserve insertion order. I mean there are cases when it seems like it does but it is not guaranteed. You can read it here https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 2):

```
File.WriteAllLines(topath, File.ReadAllLines(frompath).Distinct().ToArray());
```

Edit: modified to work in .net 3.5

Answer (score 2):

```
// Requires .NET 3.5
private void RemoveDuplicate(string sourceFilePath, string destinationFilePath)
{
    var readLines = File.ReadAllLines(sourceFilePath, Encoding.Default);

    File.WriteAllLines(destinationFilePath, readLines.Distinct().ToArray(), Encoding.Default);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PseudoCode:

```
open file reading only

List<string> list = new List<string>();

for each line in the file:
    if(!list.contains(line)):
        list.append(line)

close file
open file for writing

for each string in list:
    file.write(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

How big of a file are we talking?

One strategy could be to read the lines one at a time and load them into a data structure that you can easily check for an existing item, such as a `Hashset<int>`. I know that I can reliably hash each string line of the file using GetHashCode() (used internally to check string equality- which is what we want to determine duplicates) and just check for known hashes. So, something like

```
var known = new Hashset<int>();
using (var dupe_free = new StreamWriter(@"c:\path\to\dupe_free.txt"))
{
    foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(@"c:\path\to\has_dupes.txt")
    {
        var hash = line.GetHashCode();
        if (!known.Contains(hash)) 
        {
            known.Add(hash);
            dupe_free.Write(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternately, you can take advantage of Linq's `Distinct()` method and do it in one line, as Blindy suggested:

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\path\to\dupe_free.txt", File.ReadAllLines((@"c:\path\to\has_dupes.txt").Distinct().ToArray());
```

Comment: @LukeH right which is why my primary answer is reading and writing them in a hand written loop; the hashset is a cheap lookup, and with gethashcode it's guaranteed both correct order and uniqueness.