# How can I make all line endings (EOLs) in all files in Visual Studio Code, Unix-like?

Tags: windows, bash, visual-studio-code, editor, line-endings

I use [Windows 10 Home](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_editions#Baseline_editions) and I usually use Visual Studio Code (VS Code) to edit Linux Bash scripts as well as PHP and JavaScript.

I don't develop anything dedicated for Windows and I wouldn't mind that the default EOLs for all files I edit whatsoever would be Unix like (nix).

How could I ensure that all EOLs, in all files whatsoever (from whatever file extension), are nix, in Visual Studio Code?

---

I ask this question after I've written a few Bash scripts in Windows with Visual Studio Code, uploaded them to GitHub as part of a project, and a senior programmer that reviewed the project told me I have **Windows EOLs** there and also a **[BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)** problem that I could solve if I'll change the EOLs there to be nix (or that's what I understood, at least).

---

Because all my development is Linux-oriented, I would prefer that by default, **any** file I edit would have nix EOLs, even if it's Windows unique.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

In your project preferences, add/edit the following configuration option:

```
"files.eol": "\n"
```

This was added as of commit [639a3cb](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/commit/639a3cbcb3ac118dfaba7443e2ee3b502ff34d21), so you would obviously need to be using a version after that commit.

Note: Even if you have a single `CRLF` in the file, the above setting will be ignored and the whole file will be converted to `CRLF`. You first need to convert all `CRLF` into `LF` before you can open it in Visual Studio Code.

See also: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2957

Comment: this method does not convert ALL FILES but single file

Comment: I think there is no `vscode-all-files-eol-unix-like-solution`.

Comment: Also for me this doesn't work on git projects shared with linux envoronments. What I sometimes use is `find .  -not -path '*/.*' -type f \( -iname \*Dockerfile* -o -iname \*.sh \) -exec sed -i 's/\r//' {} \;` in addition to `git config core.eol native` and `git config core.autocrlf true`. More here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9977954/3673430

Answer (score 170):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48693007/988525) explains how to do this for all files (use files.eol in settings), but if you ever need to override that setting there's an indicator at the bottom right that you can click on and change for this one file.  Took me a while to notice that this was clickable.

[image: See CRLF in the message bar at the bottom right]

Comment: This only sets the current file. The question was how to set it for all files.

Comment: I upvoted the accepted answer, which does directly answer the question The intent of this answer was to point out that if you have an exception to the default there is an easy mechanism to change the file endings for just one file.  It must be helpful to at least some people (probably new to vscode) and they upvote?  I guess it would be better as a comment to the accepted answer?

Comment: The image of Ian could be misleading, you have to change it to `lf` that is `line feed`.

Comment: Alternatively execute `Change End Of Line Sequence` command in `Show All Commands` list (`ctrl+shift+p`).

Answer (score 140):

I searched for a simple solution for days and didn't have any success until
[I found some Git commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53475008) that changed
all files from `CRLF` to `LF`.

As [pointed out by Mats](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48692741#comment116488960_65628702), make sure to commit changes before executing
the following commands.

In the root folder type the following.

```
git config core.autocrlf false

git rm --cached -r .         # Don’t forget the dot at the end

git reset --hard
```

Comment: Make sure to commit any changes before running this! :)

Comment: If only I had seen this comment earlier.

Comment: You can express that by giving an upvote :D

Comment: omg @haidar I have been using `git config core.autocrlf false` so many times but it didn't work. And after following your 3 steps, my VSCode plays so well

Comment: [Our cc-wiki licensing, while intentionally permissive, does **require** attribution.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required)
~ * ~
Don't violate [Stack Overflow's legal terms](https://stackoverflow.blog/legal)!
~ * ~
You could for example write :
_I searched for a simple solution for days and didn't have any success until [I found some Git commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53475008) that changed all files from `CRLF` to `LF`._
~ * ~
The inclusion of that link is all it takes to save you from criticism.
(I already did this for you. This comment explains why.)

Comment: @Henke what if I found the solution on some other site and just wanted to help whoever is searching for the right answer like me? If there is an answer already available on StackOverflow that doesn't mean I took it from there. I just wrote what helped me there is no need to waste mine and yours time

Comment: Please read:
[_How to reference material written by others_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).
Your answer was well received. – Be happy about it! :-)
But why would you ever want to _deliberately_ violate
[Stack Overflow's legal terms](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing)??
You _are_ allowed to copy-paste a solution from **_anywhere_** on the
Internet.
You are _**not**_ allowed to do so _without_ attributing to that other source.
~ * ~
_I suggest you edit your answer to include the **actual** source you used._

Comment: For anyone (possibly including my future self) who wants a hint on the
_source_ of this answer's three suggested commands, and/or
_understand what they do_, here are some links.
[Git: Dealing with line endings – solution](https://www.marten-online.com/source-versioning/git-dealing-with-line-endings-solution-2.html). .
[What `git rm --cached -r .` does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63552283). .
[Docs of `git rm --cached -r .`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm). .
[The other (identical) SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53475008).

Answer (score 30):

##### **To convert the line ending for existing files**

###### **WSL**

We can use [dos2unix](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix) in [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq) or in your Shell terminal.

Install the tool:

```bash
sudo apt install dos2unix
```

Convert line endings in the current directory:

```bash
find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix
```

If there are some folders that you'd want to exclude from the conversion, use:

```bash
find -type f \
     -not -path "./<dir_to_exclude>/*" \
     -not -path "./<other_dir_to_exclude>/*" \
     -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix
```

---

> *Edited in 2023*

###### **Directly PowerShell 7+ (faster, multithreaded)**

> To install PowerShell 7 on Windows, follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows?view=powershell-7.3).

You will need to have [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) installed, and to install [dos2unix](https://chocolatey.org/install) for Chocolatey.

1. Install Chocolatey following [this instructions](https://chocolatey.org/install) if you don't have it already.
2. Install dos2unix for Chocolatey

   1. Open a PowerShell terminal as Administrator

      ```
      pwsh.exe -new_console:a
      ```
   2. Install dos2unix

      ```
      choco install dos2unix
      ```
   3. Close the Administrator terminal

      ```
      exit
      ```

Now, we can use `dos2unix` from PowerShell.

```
# Set the parameters
$path = Get-Location
$numbOfThreads = 50
$exclude_patterns = "^.*(\.git|\.idea|node_modules|\.next|\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|mp4|mkv|mp3|wav)$).*$"

# Find files to convert
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Include *.* -File -Force | Where-Object {$_.FullName -notmatch $exclude_patterns}
Write-Host "Found $($files.Count) files"

# Convert the files
$files | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    dos2unix $_.FullName
} -ThrottleLimit $numbOfThreads
```

Comment: How does it handle UTF-8 with BOM encoded files?

Comment: If you want to `find` the modern way, try ` apt install fd-find` on `debian`.

Comment: Thanks! The only solution that worked on WSL for me

Answer (score 29):

You can find the option in Visual Studio Code settings.
It's under "Text Editor"→"Files"→"Eol".
Here you can select whether you want \n or \r\n or auto.

[image]

Comment: One way to get to settings is menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings*. Another is `Ctrl` + `,`.

Comment: The `auto` option might be real `crap`.

Comment: Not a solution, still the default option is CRLF for all the files even though it is set to \n in settings. What a bug in 2022. Shame on VSCode.

Comment: I searched in the setteings for LF, CRLF, line break, linebreak,... and finally it's "Eol"  o.O

Answer (score 11):

Both existing answers are helpful but not what I needed.  I wanted to bulk convert all the newline characters in my workspace from CRLF to LF.

I made a simple extension to do it

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.keyoti-changeallendoflinesequence

In fact, here is the extension code for reference

```
'use strict';

import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import { posix } from 'path';


export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

    // Runs 'Change All End Of Line Sequence' on all files of specified type.
    vscode.commands.registerCommand('keyoti/changealleol', async function () {

        async function convertLineEndingsInFilesInFolder(folder: vscode.Uri, fileTypeArray: Array<string>, newEnding: string): Promise<{ count: number }> {
            let count = 0;
            for (const [name, type] of await vscode.workspace.fs.readDirectory(folder)) {

                if (type === vscode.FileType.File && fileTypeArray.filter( (el)=>{return name.endsWith(el);} ).length>0){ 
                    const filePath = posix.join(folder.path, name);

                    var doc = await vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(filePath);

                    await vscode.window.showTextDocument(doc);
                    if(vscode.window.activeTextEditor!==null){
                        await vscode.window.activeTextEditor!.edit(builder => { 
                            if(newEnding==="LF"){
                                builder.setEndOfLine(vscode.EndOfLine.LF);
                            } else {
                                builder.setEndOfLine(vscode.EndOfLine.CRLF);
                            }
                            count ++; 
                        });

                    } else {
                        vscode.window.showInformationMessage(doc.uri.toString());
                    }
                }

                if (type === vscode.FileType.Directory && !name.startsWith(".")){
                    count += (await convertLineEndingsInFilesInFolder(vscode.Uri.file(posix.join(folder.path, name)), fileTypeArray, newEnding)).count;
                }
            }
            return { count };
        }

        let options: vscode.InputBoxOptions = {prompt: "File types to convert", placeHolder: ".cs, .txt", ignoreFocusOut: true};
        let fileTypes = await vscode.window.showInputBox(options);
        fileTypes = fileTypes!.replace(' ', '');
        let fileTypeArray: Array<string> = [];

        let newEnding = await vscode.window.showQuickPick(["LF", "CRLF"]);

        if(fileTypes!==null && newEnding!=null){
            fileTypeArray = fileTypes!.split(',');

            if(vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders!==null && vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders!.length>0){
                const folderUri = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders![0].uri;
                const info = await convertLineEndingsInFilesInFolder(folderUri, fileTypeArray, newEnding);
                vscode.window.showInformationMessage(info.count+" files converted");

            }
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: I want to run it for specific folder and for that I am trying to edit the code, But I do I run it. Can you give some light on it?

Comment: @SiddharthChoudhary The code is a VS Code extension, so to run it you have to have it in an extension.  Good news is that you can get the extension from https://github.com/keyoti/VSCode-ChangeAllEOL - I believe you can just clone that to your machine, open it in VS Code and then press F5.  It will open a test instance of VS Code and you can see your version of the extension working.  More info https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension

Answer (score 8):

I've just faced the same issue on my Windows machine. Every time I opened a file it would set the EOL to `CRLF` (even though I explicitly set up a configuration for `lf` as people suggested). It appeared, that the problem is that I cloned my repository with the **wrong Git configuration**. It was `CRLF` by default. Anyway, here's what I did and it worked perfectly. No more `CRLF` in my workspace.

1. Set up your Git configuration to `lf` with the command `git config --global core.autocrlf false`
2. Now clone your project again: `git clone ...`
3. Set up your Visual Studio Code instance, menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings* → *Files*: *Eol* to "\n".
4. Open the project, and everything should be as expected

Answer (score 7):

For other people asking you can use the
"Files.eol" setting is Visual Studio Code to change the line ending for every file.

```
"Files.eol": "\n"   // Unix
"Files.eol": "\r\n" // Windows
```

Comment: VSCode for me required lower-case `"files.eol"`. Try: CTRL+SHIFT+P -> Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON) -> Add line "files.eol": "\r\n"

Answer (score 5):

I know this is late to the game but I was recently looking for a simple method without having to install anything else to my system.

If you have Git for windows installed then just open a Git Bash window in the desired folder and run dos2unix which appears to be bundled by default:

```
find . -name "*.filetype" -exec dos2unix {} \;
```

and it will convert all your endings to LF for you. It also ignores binary files if you get lazy and try and just use -name "*"

It helped me, hopefully helps others

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall typescript

run

```
npm install -g typescript
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

check

```
git config --global core.autocrlf
```

if it shows false. try to clone and re-run the project

Answer (score 1):

First, ensure the line endings settings on your vscode is set to `crlf`.
If you want this as a global setting press `ctr+shift+p` and type `user settings json` and select the first option to open the global settings file. If you just want it on a specific project create a `settings.json` file inside a `.vscode` folder at the base of your project. Then add this line there.

```
    ...
    "files.eol": "\r\n"
```

This doesn't solve the problem though. after every pull or after launching vscode the changes still show up. Just running a `git add .` will show no more changes which I think is what is desired but you don't want to do this every time.

To solve this, you need a .editorconfig file at the base of your project.
In it, you can add:

```
   [*]
   ...
   end_of_line = crlf
```

[My original post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74968233/11170042)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Prettier in your frontend project - add this to your `.prettierrc` config:

```json
"endOfLine": "crlf",
```

Then simply run:

```
prettier --write
```