# How to change the EOL for all files from CRLF to LF

Tags: visual-studio-code, eol

In Visual Studio Code, I have changed the default [EOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) (end-of-line token) from CRLF to LF, but this only applies to new files.
I would like to know how to change the EOL for all files at once as I have more than a hundred files and it will be hard to do it manually.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/39532890/45966](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39532890/45966) Has a solution that worked for me.
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKrA6.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKrA6.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make all line endings (EOLs) in all files in Visual Studio Code, Unix-like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48692741/how-can-i-make-all-line-endings-eols-in-all-files-in-visual-studio-code-unix)

Answer (score 198):

Run these. It works for me. Customize it with your requirements

```
git config core.autocrlf false 
git rm --cached -r . 
git reset --hard
```

Comment: in my opinion this is not the solution, if someone who uses unix enviroment will have the same end of line problems

Comment: It helps though if you make changes and the files are cached.

Comment: The best explanation I've found of what the three commands do is
[this answer on how to force Git to use LF instead of CR+LF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33424884).
~ * ~
An even older reference is
[this suggested solution on how to let Git deal with line endings](https://www.marten-online.com/source-versioning/git-dealing-with-line-endings-solution-2.html).

Comment: Between lines 2 and 3 it might be necessary to write `git stash`.

Comment: Should have been add warning to stash or commit your current change.

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me. In my case the project was configured to use CRLF line endings but I had installed Git for Windows with autocrlf false. The first line changes line endings from now on, the second line removes existing line endings in local files and the third line recreates line endings in existing files using the new autocrlf value (and will delete all local changes).

Answer (score 41):

To solve the problem in my project I used a Visual Studio Code extension called **"Change All End Of Line Sequence"**, follow the process of the extension and then save all your files.

And that's it, hope it helps somebody still looking for a quick fix.

Comment: Not sure why but it's not working for me. The other thing is "Save All" (Ctrl+k) is greyed out, I cannot use it.

Comment: thankyou so sososoooo much for this extension. this entire proccess was one of the dumbest thing I ever did as a programmer

Comment: Never would have even thought to look for an extension like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 38):

If you have a Node.js development environment and [`prettier`](https://prettier.io/) installed, one way of replacing all [CRLF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation) for LF is by running `prettier --end-of-line lf --write .` in the command line. Where the dot represents the entirety of your current working directory.

Another way is to set the `endOfLine` option to `lf` in the `.prettierrc` configuration file and place a script in your `package.json` like so:

```json
...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "format": "prettier --write ."
    ...
  }
...
```

Then, you just need to execute `npm run format` in your terminal and all files targeted by `prettier` in your project will be automatically changed and saved.

Comment: Thanks for this, it got me going in the right direction but I found I had to modify the format script as I was getting a usage error about not supplying any files. I'm using express with node so my working script is `"format": "prettier app.js **/*.js --write",`

Comment: Noice!  In my case, I had to convert all my Spring Boot project's Java files' EOL's from `LF` to `CRLF`. I had **NodeJS** already installed. So I installed prettier globally: `npm install --global prettier` and then executed Prettier in root directory: `npx prettier --end-of-line crlf --write .` ( this dot is mandatory) and that solved my issue.

Comment: `prettier --end-of-line lf --write .` if you're lazy like me and want to do all project files blindly

Comment: OMG do not do this.  Now my branch says every file has changed and not just the files for my feature :(

Answer (score 4):

If you have PowerShell or git bash or another bash-type terminal you could use:

```
$ for i in *js; do vi -c "set fileformat=unix | wq" "${i}"; done
```

As mentioned in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22604/how-to-bulk-convert-all-the-file-in-a-file-system-branch-between-unix-and-window/626954#626954.