# How to disable ^M line endings in VS Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, newline, carriage-return, line-endings

VS Code has decided to start adding `^M` characters to the end of any
line I edit.
They're not visible in the editor but `git diff` picks them up.

[image: Weird line endings.]

It wasn't doing this before, so I'm guessing I accidentally bumped some
keyboard shortcut.

Does anyone know how to turn this off and have it just use regular line
endings?

Comment: Update, it seems to only be effecting one of my repos. Still haven't figured out why.

Comment: I have the same issue that I don't remember having before but when I select lf line endings, the entire file becomes replaced as far as git diff is concerned.

Comment: Strange, I reverted to the repo version, did the same edits with geany, and the same issue appeared.  geany says the file is crlf.  time to look at the binary file....

Comment: I believe this is an issue related to Git.
See https://github.com/liximomo/vscode-sftp/issues/40.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

That's caused by the different standards used in line endings (`LineFeed` or `LF` in Linux and `CarriageReturn` + `LineFeed` or `CRLF` in Windows).

You can set the encoding you want by either of the following ways:

- Click the LF or CRLF button on the **status bar** (near the bottom right corner), then select LF or CRLF.

  [image]
- Go to the command palette (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>) and type "*end of line*" (that's the mnemonic I use) until you find the command **Change End of Line Sequence**.

Answer (score 8):

Go to Preferences and click on Settings. Than write LF in the search area. Next, click on "Files" under "Text Editor". You will see "Files: Eol". Eol means "End of line". In my case it was "auto", which means VSCode would use either LF or CRLF depending on the files.

The last step: change "auto" to "\n".

[image]

Note: this only applies to the new files.

Other solutions may be found here: [How to change EOL for all files from CLRF to LF in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49228693/how-to-change-eol-for-all-files-from-clrf-to-lf-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Searching for `LF` didn't work for me, but searching for `eol` filtered it down to that one setting.