# VSCode changing CRFL to LF on file save, and git records a change even if there is none

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, newline, core.autocrlf, lf

I've noticed a weird behavior in VSCode, when I save a file, even if I don't make any change, I can see in the low right corner that it changes from CRLF to LF. Even if I make several changes, git tracks extra lines as being added and deleted at the same time.

I'm working on Windows, and so far I had no issue, it started happening just now. I've tried setting the global setting in VSCode for EOL to CRLF, and the Prettier extension also to CRLF (since I cannot disable it), but the issue remains.

I'm new at this, couldn't find similar issue online, just instructions how to set CRLF.

Answer (score 4):

I had some problems like that, because I work in a team that have UNIX and Windows environments. I use Windows, but all files of the project was saved in repositorie as `LF` `eol`. In your case (Windows environment) you need garantee the default behavior of Git:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

With that, Git will try to change `eol` of files to CRLF in operation like (new branch, clone etc.).
Even, you could try to add `"files.eol": "\r\n"` on your user/workspace settings on VSCode, then your IDE will user CRLF as default (new files, new lines).

Answer (score 1):

If the project is based on **Angular** and you have installed 'Angular Essential' extension, please check settings of the 'EditorConfig' plugin which comes as a part of the extension.
Some of the EditorConfig properties:

```
end_of_line (on save)
insert_final_newline (on save)
trim_trailing_whitespace (on save)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure the line endings settings on your vscode is set to `crlf`.
If you want this as a global setting press `ctr+shift+p` and type `user settings json` and select the first option to open the global settings file. If you just want it on a specific project create a `settings.json` file inside a `.vscode` folder at the base of your project. Then add this line there.

```
    ...
    "files.eol": "\r\n"
```

This doesn't solve the problem though. after every pull or after launching vscode the changes still show up. Just running a `git add .` will show no more changes which I think is what is desired but you don't want to do this every time.

To solve this, you need a .editorconfig file at the base of your project.
In it, you can add:

```
   [*]
   ...
   end_of_line = crlf
```

That should be it.