# Shell script written in Notepad++, Visual Studio Code, Sublime not working as expected

Tags: bash, shell, visual-studio-code, notepad++

I have written the following code using three different ide . The code is simple it creates the database on hive, but the database name will be dynamic.

```
#!/bin/bash
year=`date +%Y`
month=`date +%m`
day=`date +%d`
echo ${year}
echo ${month}
echo ${day}
dbname=dynamic_hive_${year}_${month}_${day}
echo ${dbname}
hive -e "create database if not exists ${dbname}; use ${dbname}; drop table bins_1; CREATE TABLE bins_1 (firstname string);"
```

I uploaded this code in our environment and ran it using the java program. The java program uses the java Runtime.exec to run the script. When I see the logs though, the result is as below:

[image]

Here I am getting a space in between each echo and the database name is also not as expected. If I manually run the uploaded file doing sh testfile.sh, then I get the following result:

[image]

The database is printed but it is so weird and not as expected. In the error we can see the database is not being able to be parsed. I think the new line appears after 2020 so it does not get parsed.

If the same code I copy in my server, by doing vim and run it then it runs absolutely fine. I am so confused and I really don't know what I am missing out. This should be fairly simple but I am missing out something. If someone could help me out, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a problem with line endings.  If you check the line-ending in VSCode before copying over - it seems like your script is coming over with CRLF as a delimiter instead of just LF, perhaps?

[How to make all line endings (EOLs) in all files in Visual Studio Code, UNIX like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48692741/how-to-make-all-line-endings-eols-in-all-files-in-visual-studio-code-unix-lik/48694365#48694365)

Also, try doing "cat -vt /path/to/script" to see any odd characters after copying it over.

Comment: You can also run dos2unix on the script before actually running it.

Comment: Thank you so much Ian McGowan. It seems there odd characters in the file. As @MatiasBarrios had suggested I did the dos2unix then it worked perfectly fine. The information is also provided in the link provided by Ian. I really appreciate your help.