# Undo git rm cached -r on a clean repository

Tags: git

- I had a folder with a Visual Studio 2019 solution in it, containing some 40-ish projects.
- I wanted to add the contents to git version control.
- I ran: `git init` to create a local repository.
- I created a `.gitignore` file to exclude any `bin`, `obj`, etc. folders.
- Since my `.gitignore` rules weren't affecting the `status` result, after navigating through various SO questions, I ended up running `git rm --cached -r .` which has deleted absolutely everything **except for the very folders I wanted to exclude through `.gitignore`**.

I've checked various other questions, but they all involve existing git history, which unfortunately I don't have.

I haven't touched the repo any more, for fear of making it worse. Where did the files go? Did they get unlinked but could still be recovered through some file recovery software? Any magical command which could help me here?

Comment: Did you try git reset HEAD . ?

Comment: I did. _`fatal: ambiguous argument HEAD: unknown revision or path not in the working tree`_

Comment: output of git log?

Comment: `fatal: your current branch has no commits yet`

Comment: `git rm --cached` does not affect the working tree (the visible files), so you are not describing accurately what you did. But if you said `git rm` without ever committing anything, the deletion is permanent unless you have some other kind of backup.

Comment: Did you run `git add` at any point ?

Comment: I must've ran `git add .` in between adding files to the `gitignore` and the `git rm` (see comment on the accepted answer), since the index was deleted, but not the items listed on the `gitignore` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that Visual Studio may add some of its own quirks, about which I know nothing: this answer speaks strictly to Git.

As [matt mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63547156/undo-git-rm-cached-r-on-a-clean-repository#comment112371376_63547156), `git rm --cached` does not touch your working tree.  I speculate here that you must have run `git rm` *without* `--cached`.

You're going to want to run `git fsck --lost-found`.  This will get you your file *contents* back, but not your file *names*.  This is going to be at least somewhat painful, as you will have to manually restore each file to an appropriate name.

Below, I'll tell you what I think happened, why the above works, and what you'll need to do in some more detail.

#### Long

To understand what happened (given my assumption above), what you can do, and why this is the limit of what you can do using Git directly, it's important to understand how Git works here.  A Git *repository*—that's the stuff inside the hidden `.git` folder—is all about *commits*.  A repository does have branches, or more precisely, branch *names*, but it's really all about the commits.

Each commit stores files—that's its main purpose, to store files—and also some *metadata*, which gives information such as who made the commit, when, and so on.  The commits themselves, and the files that are stored inside them, are strictly read-only.  They are in a special Git-only format, with compression and de-duplication applied.

The de-duplication deals with the fact that each commit usually duplicates most of the files from some previous commit: by de-duplicating the files, they don't actually take any space, even though each commit has a full copy of each file.  This de-duplication is quite safe *because* no committed file can ever be changed.

But since these committed files *are* read-only (and compressed and in a format that only Git itself can read), you literally *can't* work on the committed files.  This means that the files you *do* work on *aren't* the files that are in Git.  **This is where your *working tree* comes in.**

Your working tree—I like to shorten this to *work-tree*—holds *usable* copies of each file.  You do your work within the work-tree.  The top level of your work-tree contains the hidden `.git` folder, in which Git's actual repository resides.

A new, totally-empty repository has no commits (and no branch names).  You would create the first commit by running `git commit`; this would allow branch names to exist as well.  Obviously you have not done this yet either (which is OK, but will cause some pain soon).

Before Git can make a commit, though, Git needs you to *copy* your work-tree files into somewhere that Git itself can use directly for the *next* commit you will make.  **This is Git's *index*.**  Git also calls this the *staging area*, or sometimes—rarely these days—the *cache*.  These three names all describe the same thing.

Git's index holds, in Git's compressed-and-read-only format, each of the files that Git knows about.  Each index copy is in the de-duplicated *format*, but isn't actually stored in a commit yet.  This means that these copies can be *replaced* with a new, Git-ified, ready-to-be-committed copy at any time.

The reason we call Git's index its *staging area* is that when you do make a new commit, the files that go *into* the new commit are precisely those files that are in Git's index.  Hence the copies that *are* in the index are *staged for commit*.  Once you do make a new commit, those index copies are now permanently<sup>1</sup> stored in that commit.  There's one other thing to realize about these index copies, though: the *file names* in the index are only *in the index itself*.  They have embedded slashes—converted to forward slashes even on Windows—in them, e.g., a file's name might be `d1/d2/file.ext`.  The index *cannot store folders at all*, so if the index contains `d1/d2/file.ext`, Git itself will *create* folder `d1` if needed, then *create* `d1/d2` if needed, so that Git can create `file.ext` within `d1/d2/`, so that you have a file named `file.ext` in a folder named `d2` in a folder named `d1`.

To add a new file to Git's index, or to replace the ready-to-commit *contents* of a file whose name is already in Git's index, we use the `git add` command.  You must have run something like `git add .` or `git add *` early on.  At this time, Git read through your work-tree, found *every* file in it, copied the name to Git's index, and copied-and-Git-ified that file's contents as an internal blob object.  That set up Git's index, so that your next—or rather, *first*—commit was ready to be made.

---

<sup>1</sup>Commits themselves are *mostly* permanent.  If you do manage to get rid of one, the files it has saved could be lost—but if they're de-duplicated across *other* commits that you *don't* get rid of, the saved files will be retained.  This all works automatically and you don't normally need to know anything about it: you can just imagine each commit as holding a full snapshot of every file.

---

#### Recap

Let me repeat the crucial stuff above, because it's very important in a moment:

- The *index* stores the file's name, complete with prefix directory / folder name parts.
- It's not until you run `git commit` that Git saves the *names*, even though Git carefully arranges to have the de-duplicated file *contents* ready to go, in the next commit.<sup>2</sup>

The index itself is a *temporary construct*, not saved forever.  It lasts only until you do something that updates or replaces it.  It is not copied by `git clone` either: only the *commits* (and their permanent snapshots) are copied this way.

---

<sup>2</sup>This is a time/space tradeoff: Git could pre-build its internal tree objects too, and have a very different index structure.  If Git did this, you could probably store empty folders.  But it doesn't: Git builds the tree at commit time, as if by [`git write-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-write-tree).  The original `git commit` command was a script that actually ran `git write-tree`, saved the resulting hash ID, and used [`git commit-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-tree) to make the commit that stored the tree that stored the files.

Generally, the time needed to build new tree objects is much shorter than the time needed to compress and blob-ify file contents.  So Git builds the tree objects at `git commit` time, but builds and saves the blobs in advance, at `git add` time.  In some rare cases (very deep trees) this can make `git commit` kind of slow, though it's nothing like what we used to experience in the bad old days of version control systems, before Git existed.

---

#### `git status`

At this point you ran some `git status` command(s).  What `git status` does is fairly simple, but does require knowing about commits, Git's index, and your work-tree.  Fortunately, you now know about these three:

- You have no commits yet.  For this special situation, Git uses its internal [empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452), which contains no files, as the point of reference in the next few steps.
- You have set up Git's index to contain *all* of your files from your work-tree, so that Git's index matches your work-tree.  The actual contents of the index are the files' names, internal Git blob hash IDs for the files' contents, and some cache data that you don't need to know about.
- You have, in your work-tree, all of your files, in their normal everyday form.

The `git status` command starts by printing some information: your current branch name, for instance.  We'll just skip over this part.

Next, `git status` compares the contents of the *current commit* to the contents of Git's index.  Since you're in this new-repository-no-commits-yet state, Git uses the empty tree here.  That makes every file *in* Git's index a "new file", to be committed.

Last, `git status` compares the contents of the *index* to the contents of your work-tree.  These match exactly (after accounting for the Git-only format of the index copy, that is).  When a file in the index matches the copy in your work-tree, Git says nothing—so since all files match, Git says nothing here.

What you see, then, is that every file is staged for commit, *including the binary files you did not mean to commit*.  At this point, listing such a file in `.gitignore`—or listing its containing folder—does not do any good: the file is *already in Git's index* so it *is* going to be in the next commit.

#### `git rm`

What you did next is a bit of a disaster: you ran `git rm -r .`, *without* `--cached`.

The `git rm` command is meant for removing the copies of files that are in Git's index *and*, if you leave out `--cached`, the corresponding work-tree files.  If you use `--cached`, `git rm` leaves the work-tree files alone.

The *only* files that `git rm` can remove are those mentioned in Git's index.  It will either remove *both* the index copy and the work-tree copy, or the index copy only, but if some file is *not* in the index, `git rm` won't remove it from your work-tree.

As Git doesn't actually *store* folders, `git rm` sometimes doesn't *remove* them either.  Of course, if there is a file left behind, Git literally *can't* remove it, because your computer requires that the folder exist to hold the file's name-within-folder.  Git is usually fairly good about cleaning up folder names that *Git* made, but I've seen it forget to remove some now and then.  Sometimes you might want to just go in and manually delete any empty ones (or use `git clean -d`, but be careful with `git clean`!).

#### `git fsck --lost-found`

As mentioned earlier, Git stores file *contents* in a special, read-only, Git-only format that Git calls a *blob object*.  These blob objects are *referred-to* by commits—technically, by tree objects—and/or by Git's index.  A reference to a blob makes the blob *reachable*, which is a technical term I won't actually define here.

The `git fsck` command, which isn't something you need to run in any normal situation, reads and analyzes the contents of Git's internal databases, which includes scanning through *every* internal Git object.  An important side effect<sup>3</sup> of this scan is that Git will find any "dangling" blob objects.<sup>4</sup>  Adding `--lost-found` to the `git fsck` command tells it to, in effect, *resurrect* such commits and blobs.

In your case, there are no commits at all, but all the files you `git add`-ed became blob objects.  So `git fsck` should find, for every file that was in Git's index before the disastrous `git rm -r` step, a dangling blob.  The fsck command will expand out the blob contents, writing it to a file named `.git/lost-found/other/hash`, where *`hash`* is a big ugly internal Git hash ID.

To restore your files, you will now need to look at every file in that folder.  Use its contents to determine the correct file *name*, and rename the file (or copy the contents, but renaming the file helps reduce the number of files left to inspect) into the right place.

The files' names were *only in Git's index*, which has been overwritten.  So only the *contents* can be restored mechanically, and `git fsck --lost-found` does that.  That's why you have to recover all the file *names* manually.  I have done this task myself, long ago (and probably with a smaller set of files), and it is no fun.

---

<sup>3</sup>In `git fsck`, this is a side effect.  In `git gc`, which Git runs automatically for you, it's a desired effect: this is how Git trims off dead objects, including files `git add`-ed but replaced by newer `git add`s before a commit, or added and then `git rm`-ed and never committed, for instance.

<sup>4</sup>Git distinguishes between *unreachable* and *dangling* commits and blobs here, to make `git fsck` more usable.  Since commits form chains, we can have a chain of commits that is unreachable as a whole, with all but one of these commits reachable from other commits in this same chain.  The one commit with in-degree zero in the graph is the only unreachable commit, but the whole chain itself is dangling.  Any blob objects referred-to through any commit in the chain that have an in-degree count that matches the appropriate number of tree objects in this chain are, by some definitions at least, *reachable*, but aren't reachable from outside the chain, so those too are "dangling".  You don't really need to know any of this either, but if you're familiar with graph theory, it should all make sense.

Comment: One of the most amazing answers I've read. Thank you. I think I must've done a `git add .` before running the `git rm`, since I distinctively remember typing `--cached`. Nonetheless, following your guide with `git fsck` I was able to recover all of my files (albeit, scanning through the `dangling blob`s and renaming the files). Life-saver, thank you!