# How can i change the visual code standard CRLF for LF?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My standard value for a file in visual code is CRLF, how can i make my standard for every file in visual code be LF?

[image]

Comment: search settings for `EOL`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make all line endings (EOLs) in all files in Visual Studio Code, Unix-like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48692741/how-can-i-make-all-line-endings-eols-in-all-files-in-visual-studio-code-unix)

Comment: Both answers worked, thank you both so much!

Comment: This question is asked before.
Check answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48692741/how-can-i-make-all-line-endings-eols-in-all-files-in-visual-studio-code-unix/65628702#65628702)

Answer (score 5):

You can follow `File` -> `Preferences` -> `Setting` -> Search for EOL and change it to `\n`

[Where to find Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgMF3.png)