# why do I always get a syntax error in shell script running inside a container

Tags: docker, shell

I'm trying to run a shell script to build a docker image, but always getting a error that I cannot correct:

```
Neomind_dev     | build.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\r''
'eomind_dev     | build.sh: line 3: `fi
```

but the code is super simple:

```
if [ ! "$(ls /usr/local/fusion)" ]; then 
    echo aaa
fi 
cp /usr/local/fusion/target/fusion-Neomind-dev.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/fusion.war
```

can someone help me?

Comment: As an aside (the linked duplicate is on-point for your real problem): Note that using `ls` in scripts is not good practice. If you want to detect whether `/usr/local/fusion` exists, `if [ -e /usr/local/fusion ]; then` or `if test -e /usr/local/fusion; then` will do so more efficiently (without spawning off a subshell and then invoking an external executable within it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
dos2unix your_script.sh
```

or

```
sed -i 's/\r//' your_script.sh
```

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_, and therein the bullet point regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before".

Comment: I run the script in dockerfile like this

"CMD /bin/bash build.sh"

Should i pass this sed -i after the bash?

Comment: @LucasFellipeMondiniPereira, this should be done _on the source files_ that Docker is reading -- that includes `build.sh` -- _before_ Docker starts.

Comment: @LucasFellipeMondiniPereira, ...how to change the file type depends on which editor you're using. For example, in vim, `:set fileformat=unix` will stop it from using DOS/Windows CRLF newlines and make it switch to UNIX-format LFs. If these files are from source control, all major SCMs (git, svn, cvs, etc) all let you control which line ending type text files are checked out with.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @NicoHaase, on a duplicate it would be better if the answer was just deleted -- that way the explanation on the answers on the preexisting duplicate can be used, or extended as-needed. We don't need answers covering the same ground spread across many questions when they could be consolidated to have a single focus for edits/voting/comments/other quality enhancement efforts.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i'm using vscode; i'm actually coding in windows and just running the script on the container, wich is a linux

Comment: @LucasFellipeMondiniPereira, so the next question is how to make VS Code on Windows save your files in UNIX format. I bet if you search you'll find an answer elsewhere on this site.

Comment: @LucasFellipeMondiniPereira, ...and indeed, it _is_ already asked-and-answered: [How can I make all line endings (EOLs) in all files in Visual Studio Code UNIX-like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48692741/how-can-i-make-all-line-endings-eols-in-all-files-in-visual-studio-code-unix)