# How do you remove blank lines from an XML document or node using C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, xmlnode

I want all the blank lines to be removed in the XML  below before writing it to document. It may help to know that I used the .DeleteSelf() method of the XPathNavigator class to get rid of the unwanted nodes before (and that only leaves empty lines).

```
    <Person xmlns="http://someURI.com/something">
      <FirstName>Name1</FirstName>











       <MiddleName>Name2</MiddleName>


       <LastName>Name3</LastName>




     </Person>
```

Comment: Have you tried to load such of content into `XDocument` then to save it as xml file?

Comment: Refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/6480081/1513471

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the simplest way to get indented XML with line breaks from XmlDocument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203528/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-get-indented-xml-with-line-breaks-from-xmldocument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to use `XDocument` class:

**1. method:**

```
string xcontent = @" strange xml content here ";
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xcontent);
xdoc.Save("FullFileName.xml");
```

**2. method:**

```
XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xcontent));
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(rdr);
xdoc.Save("FullFileName.xml");
```

returns:

```
<Person xmlns="http://someURI.com/something">
  <FirstName>Name1</FirstName>
  <MiddleName>Name2</MiddleName>
  <LastName>Name3</LastName>
</Person>
```

Msdn documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Can also do line by line reading and writing.

```
            string line = string.Empty;
            using (StreamReader file_r = new System.IO.StreamReader("HasBlankLines.xml"))
            {
                using (StreamWriter file_w = new System.IO.StreamWriter("NoBlankLines.xml"))
                {
                    while ((line = file_r.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (line.Trim().Length > 0)
                            file_w.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Outputs:

```
<Person xmlns="http://someURI.com/something">
    <FirstName>Name1</FirstName>
    <MiddleName>Name2</MiddleName>
    <LastName>Name3</LastName>
</Person>
```

Comment: This assumes that none of the elements' values is a text node with empty lines in it intentionally.